# How to quickly check if object attribute exists on conditional object type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an example below that is an extremely simplified version of my actual code.

I have a type that can either be an interface or another like so:

```js
interface ChatBase {
    roomId?: string
    type: "message" | "emoji"
    configs: unknown
}
interface ChatMessage extends ChatBase {
    type: "message",
    configs:{
        text?: string
    }
}
interface ChatEmoji extends ChatBase {
    type: "emoji",
    configs: {
        emoji?: string
    }
}
type Chat =  ChatMessage | ChatEmoji
```

Here is a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=50&ssc=3&pln=25&pc=1#code/LAKFEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrABAYQBbOgELIDOmA3qBlRvAPa0C2AkgCYD8AXBsdPFAOaVq0AJ4AHWFwBEDWMWLJ%20sKRgA%20GKbAa0AVuClCqqWpETh%20xLgFdIAa0i0A7pFABfUB5BQ4SNJlz4ALJyCkoYsAAecJAsxNh4hCTkhhiiEtKy8orKADQpxqbmlhQg1GWpkdCc3LwCKe4gDd4IKOjx%20ACi2nrhUbAxcQGJpBglZWmSGlq6%20nml1AVmFlxj5VTTetU8fJCC81QNDaAT7dAYALxUQ8FZYepDXTOeBTwYqAmWpwDaALoXGF8Uqs1hMMiFslI5msjCYlp9gdCqHAotJtgIDPtyg0yq4odQEeNxJNNN1ZikyosiitydCNuBUbVdhjEdjqA0fs8PgA6BjIMQACne%20HOAD4EeBEIKElzKRYuXSAJQEhYmYi0AA2sC56to-H5UgAEiQMMhIOFSVIFfUUhL9XSVFA3tLZXEAGSup34GWwory0lKmkwyBqzXa3X6o1xU3mmaW62Y21C6Bck7nNNTC0Yd2e5Muv0zAOYimqjVanV6w3G-oxvRxzGHBVAA)

Now in my code, when I try to simply check if "emoji" is defined in `configs`, it's making it super more complicated, surely there is a simpler way?

```js
const chats: Chat[] = [
    { type: "message", configs: { text: "string" } },
    { type: "emoji", configs: { emoji: "string" } }
]

chats.map(chat=>{
    if(chat.configs.emoji){ // <=== THROWS ERROR SHOWN BELOW
        console.log("Has an emoji")
    }
    if("emoji" in chat.configs && chat.configs.emoji){ // <= Works but ridiculously long
        console.log("Has an emoji")
    }
    if(chat.type === "emoji" && chat.configs.emoji){ // <= Works but sometimes I test for shared properties
        console.log("Has en emoji")
    }
})
```

But typescript is throwing me an error

```
Property 'emoji' does not exist on type '{ text?: string | undefined; }'.
```

So my question is, how can I can I make `if("emoji" in chat.configs && chat.configs.emoji)` not ridiculously long?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the last method, you can check for shared properties before narrowing the type down no?

Comment: I guess, at the risk of extending the question, why would it even throw an error in the first place?

Comment: Because it's not looking at the fact that the property access is in an if statement, it's just telling you that property doesn't always exist, so you have to narrow the type down before using it.

Comment: It feels like it should throw an error if it is never declared in any interfaces, especially since I'm checking it.

Comment: Relating to your first comment, I simplified this example, in my code, I have over 16 interfaces on this type, of which 6ish share some common properties. So filtering would be a hand full...

Comment: A type predicate might help to simplify it a bit, but it does open the door for human error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates ie. you can make a function that says "this object is of type ChatEmoji and configs.emoji is defined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250076/discussion-between-denislexic-and-chris-hamilton).

Answer (score 1):

A type predicate might help to simplify things: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

```js
function hasDefinedEmoji(chat: Chat): chat is ChatEmoji & {configs: {emoji: string}} {
    return chat.type === "emoji" && Boolean(chat.configs.emoji);
}
```

```js
if(hasDefinedEmoji(chat)){
    console.log("Has an emoji", chat.configs.emoji) // works
}
```

The drawback is you can make a mistake in the predicate function and shoot yourself in the foot. You could do this and typescript won't bat an eye:

```js
function hasDefinedEmoji(chat: Chat): chat is ChatEmoji & {configs: {emoji: string}} {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply define a type predicate for each type (if needed) in a helper file:

```
const isChatEmoji = (chat: ChatBase): chat is ChatEmoji => chat.type === "emoji";
const isChatMessage = (chat: ChatBase): chat is ChatMessage => chat.type === "message";
```

You can then do:

```
chats.filter(isChatEmoji).forEach(chat => console.log(chat.configs.emoji));
```